# Consolidate stream of json objects with jq

Tags: jq

Premise: Looking to parse stream of objects from a json log file and output the total number of times "id.orig_h" connects to "id.resp_h" based on certain conditions and show the total count.

Sample json input:

```
jq --slurp --raw-output . 
   
  {
    "ts": 1636606.998991,
    "uid": "CgbTrLvhqHAa",
    "id.orig_h": "10.8.21.11",
    "id.orig_p": 54858,
    "id.resp_h": "10.8.21.66",
    "id.resp_p": 5044,
    "proto": "tcp",
    "conn_state": "S0",
    "local_orig": true,
    "local_resp": true,
    "missed_bytes": 0,
    "history": "S",
    "orig_pkts": 1,
    "orig_ip_bytes": 60,
    "resp_pkts": 0,
    "resp_ip_bytes": 0
  },
  {
    "ts": 1636638.028568,
    "uid": "CFNumGx3XYWW7",
    "id.orig_h": "fe80::ba:61:fe3f:80",
    "id.orig_p": 130,
    "id.resp_h": "ff02::1",
    "id.resp_p": 131,
    "proto": "icmp",
    "duration": 3420.447889374,
    "orig_bytes": 2608,
    "resp_bytes": 0,
    "conn_state": "OTH",
    "local_orig": false,
    "local_resp": false,
    "missed_bytes": 0,
    "orig_pkts": 163,
    "orig_ip_bytes": 11736,
    "resp_pkts": 0,
    "resp_ip_bytes": 0
  },
  {
    "ts": 1636526872.598889,
    "uid": "Cq9JTE1OweOW6mi",
    "id.orig_h": "fe::63:88:14f5:b5",
    "id.orig_p": 131,
    "id.resp_h": "ff02::fb",
    "id.resp_p": 130,
    "proto": "icmp",
    "duration": 81086.88094513,
    "orig_bytes": 64000,
    "resp_bytes": 0,
    "conn_state": "OTH",
    "local_orig": false,
    "local_resp": false,
    "missed_bytes": 0,
    "orig_pkts": 4000,
    "orig_ip_bytes": 288000,
    "resp_pkts": 0,
    "resp_ip_bytes": 0
  },
  {
    "ts": 1636604547.798971,
    "uid": "Cs41IjaZTAdF7f",
    "id.orig_h": "fe::63:88:14f5:b5",
    "id.orig_p": 131,
    "id.resp_h": "ff02::1:ff:b5",
    "id.resp_p": 130,
    "proto": "icmp",
    "duration": 3414.3990546265,
    "orig_bytes": 2608,
    "resp_bytes": 0,
    "conn_state": "OTH",
    "local_orig": false,
    "local_resp": false,
    "missed_bytes": 0,
    "orig_pkts": 163,
    "orig_ip_bytes": 11736,
    "resp_pkts": 0,
    "resp_ip_bytes": 0
   }
```

I believe the conditions part is good

```
    jq -r '. | select(.resp_ip_bytes > 0 and .orig_ip_bytes > 0 and .duration > 0 and .orig_bytes > 0 and .resp_bytes >0)'
```

However every time I try a

```
    group_by([."id.orig_h", ."id.resp_h"]),
```

getting --> Cannot index number with string "id.orig_h"

Desired Output:

```
1.1.1.1 -> 2.2.2.2 | XXXX <- # of times
```

Here is the output without the join(" ")

```
jq -sr 'map(select(.resp_ip_bytes > 0 and .orig_ip_bytes > 0 and .duration > 0 and .orig_bytes > 0 and .resp_bytes >0)) | group_by([."id.orig_h", ."id.resp_h"]) | map(length as $count | .[] | .count = $count) | sort_by([-.count, -.resp_ip_bytes]) | first | [."id.orig_h", "->", ."id.resp_h", "|", .count]'
[
  "10.8.21.11",
  "->",
  "10.8.21.123",
  "|",
  225 <--(not sure it matters but output on .count is yellow, all other output is green)
]
```

With the join(" ")

```
string (" ") and number (225) cannot be added
```

Comment: Added more json input containing all fields from jq request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```sh
jq --slurp --raw-output '
  map(select(.resp_ip_bytes > 0 ... your conditions here ...))
  | group_by([."id.orig_h", ."id.resp_h"])
  | map(length as $count | .[] | .count = $count)
  | sort_by([-.count, -.resp_ip_bytes]) | first
  | [."id.orig_h", "->", ."id.resp_h", "|", .count]
  | join(" ")
'
```

This inserts another field value `count` with the number of connections, then sorts first by the highest `count`, then by the highest `resp_ip_bytes`, takes the first match an formats the output as desired.

Comment: Input:
```
    jq -sr '
    map(select(.resp_ip_bytes > 0 and .orig_ip_bytes > 0 and .duration > 0 and .orig_bytes > 0 and .resp_bytes >0 and .resp_pkts > 0)) 
        | group_by([."id.orig_h", ."id.resp_h"]) 
        | map(first."id.orig_h", "->", first."id.orig_h", "|", length) 
        | join(" ")
    '
```
Output:
````
jq: error (at <stdin>:3515): string (" ") and number (1) cannot be added
```

Comment: You introduced `.resp_pkts` in the conditions which does not exist in your sample data. Leaving out `and .resp_pkts > 0`, it works as expected: [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/4AZthlDtg6)

Comment: Might have sent you down the wrong rabbit hole... Instead of returning each conversation, I'm hoping to return just the single most frequent connection between id.orig_h and id.resp_h with the total count of how frequently the two hosts connected (aka entries into the json log file. 

Sorry for any confusion, us net-eng folks are used to speaking in packets, lol...

When plugged into jq play, I get
10.3.8.31 -> 10.8.21.11 | 2 10.8.21.11 -> 10.8.21.66 | 1 10.8.21.11 -> 10.8.21.123 | 1
returned

Comment: The "just the single [...] connection between id.orig_h and id.resp_h with the total count of how frequently the two hosts connected" is exactly what I suppose my answer is doing - provided that by "how frequently" the size (`length`) of each grouping (after filtering out your conditions) is what we can agree on. The only thing unclear to me is what I left out from my quote in the beginning of this post: "the single **most frequent** connection". What makes it the most frequent? We are only returning the two IPs and the count. There is no "single connection" recognizable anymore, or is it?

Comment: Thinking I would just need to sort_by length to get the most frequent connection

Comment: How many rows do you expect in total? One (the most frequent) or one for each pair of IPs?

Comment: "One (the most frequent)"

Comment: Ok, and if there's not one but many (equally) most frequent, which one should it be then?

Comment: The one with the largest value for "resp_ip_bytes" - if possible, I know this is beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: Sorry, had to go earlier. Now back again and rewrote my answer according to your clarifications. Hope this time we got it right. (Highest `resp_ip_bytes` can still be a tie though)

Comment: leaving off the join(" ") and piping to "@tsv" or "@csv" displays correctly. Not sure this is programmatically correct, but... LOL. 

Can't thank you enough for your patience and assistance in working through the issue.

Comment: You're welcome! Just fiddling around: You could also replace the last two lines (the array and the `join`) with `| "\(."id.orig_h") -> \(."id.resp_h") | \(.count)"`

Answer (score 0):

Although the built-in `group_by` is convenient, it can be very inefficient with respect to both space and time, and the following alternative may be especially appropriate in the context of very long log files.

Notice that `inputs` is used with the -n command-line option:

```
< log.json jq -nr '
# Emit a stream of arrays, each array being a group defined by a value of f,
# which can be any jq filter that produces exactly one value for each item in `stream`.
def GROUPS_BY(stream; f): 
   reduce stream as $x ({};
     ($x|f) as $s
     | ($s|type) as $t
     | (if $t == "string" then $s else ($s|tojson) end) as $y
     | .[$t][$y] += [$x] )
   | .[][] ;

GROUPS_BY(inputs
          | select(.resp_ip_bytes > 0 and
                   .orig_ip_bytes > 0 and
                   .duration > 0 and .orig_bytes > 0 and
                   .resp_bytes >0);
          [."id.orig_h", ."id.resp_h"] ) 
| (first | "\(."id.orig_h") -> \(."id.resp_h")" ) +
  ( .[]  | " | \(length)" )
'
```

---

Notes:

a) `GROUPS_BY` as defined above is stream-oriented, both with respect to its input and its output.  Apart from that, the main functional difference between `GROUPS_BY` and `group_by` is that the latter involves a sort.

b) `GROUPS_BY/2` as defined above is relatively complex because it is designed to have the full generality of `group_by`, for which it is almost a plug-in alternative. Specifically, `E | group_by(F)` is functionally equivalent to:

```
[GROUPS_BY(E[]; F)] | sort_by(F)
```